# How to make software under mono and wine use the bookmarks of Nautilus when opening files

Tags: nautilus, wine, mono, bookmarks

When opening files in some Ubuntu native software, there is an interface that can use the bookmarks of Nautilus.

But when using software run under mono or wine, there seems no apparent way to use Nautilus bookmarks. I wonder how to use Nautilus bookmarks when opening files under mono or wine software?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Wine and Mono cannot do this for the same reason - they implement their own file save/open dialogs, and those do not know about the Nautilus bookmark system.  However, your question has inspired me to investigate this issue in Wine upstream, you can follow the mailing lis thread here: http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2011-December/093482.html